# How java lock knows what resources should be locked

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I'm learning Java concurrency, and in many instances I saw

```
    try{
       writeLock.lock();
       // ...
    } finally {
       writeLock.unlock();
    }
```

However, I'm wondering how does the Java compiler knows what resources should be locked inside the body of the try statement because there's no explicit indication of what objects are locked?

Comment: Java doesn't do anything beyond locking the resource. The lock will pause the calling thread until other thread (that has locked the lock before) will unlock, so only one thread at a time will access the critical code in the try body.

Comment: It doesn’t know. That’s why it is *your* duty to consistently use the same lock object to protect access to the same resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object that is locked is 'writeLock'.

The resources that you presumably intend to protect by using the lock are only protected to the extent that you have carefully ensured that all accesses to those resources use the lock in the manner you intend.

If the code shown is all the code there is (that accesses the protected resources) then you're good.  But if you've written code elsewhere that modifies those same resources without first acquiring the same writeLock, then you likely have concurrency bugs.